# Highcharts Horizontal stacked bar, reduce space between bar and x-axis

Tags: highcharts

I have been working on a horizontal stacked bar in highchart. I need to remove the space between the x-axis and the bar in the chart. 
You can get the details from this image:

[image].

Below are the chart options:

```
{
"chart":{
    "type":"bar",
    "renderTo":"ConfigurationTickets"
},
"title":{
    "text":null
},
"xAxis":{
    "groupPadding":0
},
"yAxis":{
    "min":0,
    "title":{
        "text":null
    },
    "gridLineWidth":0,
    "labels":{
        "enabled":true
    },
    "minorTickLength":0,
    "tickLength":0,
    "minPadding":0.5,
    "maxPadding":0.5
},
"legend":{
    "enabled":false,
    "reversed":true
},
"plotOptions":{
    "series":{
        "stacking":"percent",
        "minPointLength":1,
        "pointWidth":20,
        "pointPadding":0,
        "point":{
            "events":{

            }
        },
        "column":{
            "pointPadding":0,
            "groupPadding":0
        },
        "showInLegend":false,
        "softThreshold":true
    },
    "cursor":"pointer",
    "bar":{
        "groupPadding":0.1,
        "pointWidth":20,
        "pointPadding":0
    }
},
"series":[
    {
        "data":[
            {
                "y":3,
                "color":"#ac89cb"
            }
        ],
        "name":"more than 31"
    },
    {
        "data":[
            {
                "y":2,
                "color":"#8d749a"
            }
        ],
        "name":"21 - 30"
    },
    {
        "data":[
            {
                "y":3,
                "color":"#72557b"
            }
        ],
        "name":"Less than 20"
    }
]}
```

Comment: I am not sure how you would like to show your chart but I think that you can use marginBottom and marginTop in your case: http://jsfiddle.net/muyz8rjz/

Comment: That space is a result of 1) your chart height, 2) your top and bottom margins, 3) your series `pointRange` and/or `pointWidth`, as well as the `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` 4) your `xAxis` `minPadding` and `maxPadding` settings. | How to solve your problem depends on what you actually want. Do you want the bar to fill that space? Do you want your chart to be shorter? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

So, you had a lot of things out of place in your chart options.

Here's an example that uses this updated code to fill the space with the bar:

```
"plotOptions": {
  "series": {
    "stacking": "percent",
    "minPointLength": 1,
    "pointPadding": 0,
            "groupPadding": 0,
            "cursor": "pointer"
  }
}
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/muyz8rjz/1/